# running unit tests of schematics/scully

Tags: scully

After having forked `scully`, running `npm test` from the root folder launches `jest` tests but doesn't launch the unit tests with jasmine under ./schematics/scully.

When running `npm test` from under ./schematics/scully, it doesn't work:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:atao60/scully.git

cd scully/schematics/scully

npm i

npm i -D guess-parser@^0.4.13 @angular/core@"^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0-0" @angular/common@"^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0-0"

npm i -D bufferutil@^4.0.1 utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 zone.js@~0.10.3 typescript@"~3.7.5 || ~3.8.0"

npm test
#
# > @scullyio/init@0.0.26 test /home/pierre/DevSpace/gh-pages-explo/scully/schematics/scully
# > npm run build && jasmine src/**/*_spec.js
#
#
# > @scullyio/init@0.0.26 build /home/pierre/DevSpace/gh-pages-explo/scully/schematics/scully
# > tsc -p tsconfig.json
#
# Randomized with seed 75077
# Started
# FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
#
# Failures:
# 1) add-post when using `metaDataFile` option should add the meta data but keep title from options
#   Message:
#     Error: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/package.json'
#     Require stack:
#     - /home/pierre/DevSpace/gh-pages-explo/scully/schematics/scully/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/node-module-engine-host.js
#     - /home/pierre/DevSpace/gh-pages-explo/scully/schematics/scully/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/workflow/node-workflow.js
#     - /home/pierre/DevSpace/gh-pages-explo/scully/schematics/scully/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
#     - /home/pierre/DevSpace/gh-pages-explo/scully/schematics/scully/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/testing/schematic-test-runner.js
#     - /home/pierre/DevSpace/gh-pages-explo/scully/schematics/scully/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/testing/index.js
#     - /home/pierre/DevSpace/gh-pages-explo/scully/schematics/scully/src/add-blog/index_spec.js
#     - /home/pierre/DevSpace/gh-pages-explo/scully/schematics/scully/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
#     - /home/pierre/DevSpace/gh-pages-explo/scully/schematics/scully/node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js
#   Stack:
#     error properties: Object({ code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [ '/home/pierre/DevSpace/
# [...]
#
# 33 specs, 33 failures
# Finished in 0.465 seconds
# Randomized with seed 75077 (jasmine --random=true --seed=75077)
# npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

It seems I missed something obvious but I can't figure out what. Any clue'd be welcome.

Comment: I think this question should go directly to Scully Issues - https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues

Comment: It's been done since, see https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues/522

Comment: so.. was it solved?

Comment: See https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues/633